# Parts of rigs and items wont show in the final render

Tags: rendering

I have tried all the visibility Icon in the object menu as well as the camera in the outlier.  Neither are the case and I dont know what is going on.[image]

[image]

Comment: Check they may be on a layer that is excluded from rendering in the Render Layers panel. Easy way to check is move them to the same layer as the visible object.

Comment: I know this isnt the case.  All the characters, minus the one on the far left (our left not theirs) are on 1 layer.  And rendering it I only get the arms and legs of the character on the far right.  And I checked the Scene tab, no layers are excluded, and all are selected for rendering

Comment: I did what you said and yea it didnt help, thanks for  trying  though

Comment: Might want to upload it here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/ for a closer look then...

Comment: Can I just link it through Google Drive?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B32rqUsrm9xWMXBpcVE4MHpXd0U

Comment: @TheLastWarrior no we do not like to use google drive, because inevitably the link will go down, then we are left with a question with yet another dead link. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Answer (score 0):

Select your objects on the second layer and press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose to *Clear Restricted Render*. Should all be fine now.

Comment: Glad to help. Maybe accept the answer to close the topic ?